# For which groups does existence of a subgroup of prime index $p$ implies the existence of a subgroup order $p$?

Tags: group-theory

Subgroups and quotient groups are very different things, but when $G$ is finite and has a quotient group $Q$ of order $p$ with $p$ prime we know from Cauchy's theorem (or the stronger, more famous version by Sylow) that $G$ also has a subgroup $H$ of order $p$. (Here I have no pretensions as to elements of $H$ being representatives of elements of $Q$ although results in that direction would be nice too)

My question is: is there a more general class of groups than just finite groups for which this implication (subgroup of index $p$ implies subgroup of order $p$) holds?

The example of $\mathbb{Z}$, the infinite cyclic group shows that this property is not automatic, but still I am cautiously optimistic about compact topological groups. And what is known about reductive algebraic groups?

Comment: Do you have any example? I mean do you know of some infinite group $G$ where there exists a (normal?) subgroup $K$ such that $|G:K|$ is finite and a prime number (called $p$), and $G$ also has a subgroup $H$ of the same order, $|H|=p$?

Comment: Just take a direct product of a group of order $p$ with any infinite group.

Comment: @Jeppe: Besides Derek's example there is an other class of examples I was thinking of: the orthogonal groups O(n) which contain SO(n) as an index 2 subgroup (admitted: for n odd they are products, but that seems a bit irrelevant here). The smallest of these O(n) is the symmetry group of the circle and as such'feels' like the $n \to \infty$ of the dihedral groups (symmetry groups of $n$-gons) but there is also a discrete infinite dihedral group with $\mathbb{Z}$ as a index 2 subgroup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The $p$-adic integers are a torsion-free compact topological group with a quotient of order $p$.

Comment: A yes a very nice example! Now that compact topological group is not the appropriate generalization of finite group I am becoming more sceptic that such a generalization exists but I still hope some-one finds one!